# Does Darth Vader's punishing grip star card, make his choke do more damage?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

Darth Vader has a star card called Punishing Grip.  It increases the length of his choke based on the level you've upgraded the card to.  This is useful for dropping enemies off cliffs, but does it increase the amount of damage it does, or does it do the same amount of damage, except over time?